# No se ejecutan eventos de MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Buenas tardes/ Buenos días

Estoy desarrollando una página web y le estoy haciendo un método para verificar la existencia del correo, para eso genero un código único y se los envío por php y subo ese código a una base de datos, quiero que ese código se elimine en cierto tiempo, para eso uso eventos en MySQL, la fecha a subo en formato: HH:MM:00 No ocupo segundos para que sea exacto y no de problemas la ejecución del evento, pero no sé como especificar que quiero que compare la hora de registro y la hora actual menos x minutos:

```
CREATE EVENT delete_code
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE
DO DELETE FROM `verf` WHERE TIME = ();
```

No sé que poner en la condición. Ayuda por favor.

Creo ya encontre la solución:

```
DO DELETE FROM `verf` WHERE `TIME` = Date_format(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE), "%H:%i:00")
```

PERO:

Ahora no se ejecuta el evento, no hace nada después de crearlo.

Comment: ¿No funciona si lo pones así simplemente: `DO DELETE FROM verf WHERE TIME = NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE`